# Как удалить дубликаты линий из файла?

Tags: linux, bash

Есть файл `test.txt`

```
1
2
3
```

Данный код возвращает дубликаты

```
awk '!a[$0]++' test.txt
```

Как удалить дубликаты из того же файла. Я пробовал вот так, но результирующий файл уже пустой

```
awk '!a[$0]++' test.txt > test.txt
```

Comment: А вам именно `awk` нужен? Есть же другие способы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте промежуточный файл:

```
awk '!a[$0]++' test.txt >tmp && mv -f tmp test.txt
```

Тест https://repl.it/repls/UnpleasantBlindDisplaymanager

Ещё вот так можно:

```
sort -u -o test.txt test.txt
```

Тест https://repl.it/repls/WorthlessFakeKeyboardmapping